# Is there a way to use calc() with fit-content or anything similar?

Tags: html, css, sass

I need to set the height of a div with `fit-content minus 15px`. Is there a way to do that without JS?
I've tried with `calc()`, but it didn't work.

My goal is to set the height dynamically to an element with several `p` within it. Each one of these `p` has a `border-bottom`, but I don't want the border of the last one to be showed, for peculiar reasons, the framework I'm using doesn't accept `last-child` or `last-of-type`, so I'm trying to hide the border shortening the height of the container.

```css
.wrapper {
  width: 100px;
  background: red;
  height: calc(fit-content - 15px)
}

.child {
  height: 100px;
  width: 50px;
  background: blue;
}
```

```html
<div class="wrapper">
  <div class="child"></div>
</div>
```

P.S. I'm using sass in this project, but I'm not familiar with it.

Comment: what your goal? you want an overflow of 15px ?

Comment: @Temani Afif I need to set the height dynamically to an element with several `p`. Each one of these `p` has a `border-bottom`, but I don't want the border of the last one to be showed, for peculiar reasons, the framework I'm using doesn't accept `last-child` or `last-of-type`, so I'm trying to hide the border shortening the height of the container.

Comment: Why not adding such description to your question? you don't need to deal with fit-content or calc(), you can solve your border-bottom issue differently (using clip-path for example).

Comment: the answer is NO becuase `fit-content` is not a number so `calc` will not work

Comment: @Temani Afif I update the question. How would that work with `clip-path`?

Comment: `clip-path:inset(0 0 15px 0)`

Comment: @Paulie_D I figured that out, but I thought that could be some way around.

Comment: @Temani Afif That worked great. Thank you very much. If want to edit it as a question I would be happy to accept it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `clip-path` to cut `15px` from the bottom

```css
.wrapper {
  width: 100px;
  background: red;
  clip-path: inset(0 0 15px 0);
}

.child {
  height: 100px;
  border-bottom: 15px solid green; /* you will not see this */
  width: 50px;
  background: blue;
}
```

```html
<div class="wrapper">
  <div class="child"></div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use `::after` or `::before`

```css
.wrapper{
   position: relative;
   z-index: 2;
}
.wrapper::after {
   content: '';
   position: absolute;
   inset: 0;
   z-index: 1;
   width: 100%;
   height: calc(100% - 15px);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Mask to hide the bottom `15px`

```css
.wrapper {
  width: 100px;
  background: red;
  -webkit-mask: linear-gradient(#000 0 0) 0 -15px no-repeat;
}

.child {
  height: 100px;
  width: 50px;
  border-bottom: 15px solid; 
  background: blue;
}
```

```html
<div class="wrapper">
  <div class="child"></div>
</div>
```